# Given collection of strings, count number of times each word appears in List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, regex, linq

Input 1: `List<string>`, e.g:

> "hello", "world", "stack", "overflow".

Input 2: `List<Foo>` (two properties, string a, string b), e.g:

> Foo 1:
>     a: "Hello there!"
>     b: string.Empty
>
> Foo 2:
>     a: "I love Stack Overflow"
>     b: "It's the best site ever!"

So i want to end up with a `Dictionary<string,int>`. The word, and the number of times it appears in the `List<Foo>`, either in the `a` **or** the `b` field.

Current first-pass/top of my head code, which is far too slow:

```
var occurences = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (var word in uniqueWords /* input1 */)
{
    var aOccurances = foos.Count(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.a) && x.a.Contains(word));
    var bOccurances = foos.Count(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.b) && x.b.Contains(word));
    occurences.Add(word, aOccurances + bOccurances);
}
```

Comment: What is the use of `input1`?

Comment: If first list is list of words (i.e. "help" and you don't need to match "helpless dog") than you can tokenize strings in `List<Foo>` first (and put in dictionary for each Foo) and match would be much faster.

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad - that's the list of words i want to match on (e.g count the number of occurences)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - code please?

Comment: @Aron already provided reasonable code that converts 2 strings (combined with space in between) into dictionary with word count. Just keep your current iteration by instead of Contains use ContainsKey (or TryGetValue) - free count...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly:

1. Build a dictionary (`occurrences`) from the first input, optionally with a case-insensitive comparer.
2. For each `Foo` in the second input, use `RegEx` to split `a` and `b` into words.
3. For each word, check if the key exists in `occurrences`. If it exists, increment and update the value in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You could try concating the two strings a + b. Then doing a regex to pull out all the words into a collection. Then finally indexing that using a group by query.

For example

```
void Main()
{
    var a = "Hello there!";
    var b =  "It's the best site ever!";

    var ab = a + " " + b;

    var matches = Regex.Matches(ab, "[A-Za-z]+");
    var occurences = from x in matches.OfType<System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match>()
                    let word = x.Value.ToLowerInvariant()
                    group word by word into g
                    select new { Word = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
    var result = occurences.ToDictionary(x => x.Word, x => x.Count);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Example with some changes suggested...
Edit. Just reread the requirement....kinda strange but hey...

```
void Main()
{
    var counts = GetCount(new [] {
        "Hello there!",
        "It's the best site ever!"
    });
    Console.WriteLine(counts);
}


public IDictionary<string, int> GetCount(IEnumerable<Foo> inputs)
{
    var allWords =      from input in inputs
                        let matchesA = Regex.Matches(input.A, "[A-Za-z']+").OfType<System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match>()
                        let matchesB = Regex.Matches(input.B, "[A-Za-z']+").OfType<System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match>()
                        from x in matchesA.Concat(matchesB)
                        select x.Value;
    var occurences = allWords.GroupBy(x => x, (x, y) => new{Key = x, Count = y.Count()}, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    var result = occurences.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Now I know there are a few bugs in here, especially with European languages. Also its doing something slightly different from your code. Since I am not going to match "stack" or "overflow" to "stackoverflow".

Comment: Instead of `OfType<Match>()`, I would suggest `from Match x in matches` (which translates to `Cast<Match>()` behind the scenes, and reads better).

Comment: @dahlbyk Thanks for that. Very much a stylistic thing. Personally I tend to use my own casting function for safety, HOWEVER +1 for adding something I've never seen before!

Comment: Reasonable tokenization. Missing outer portion of the search, but it could be enough to get number of matching words in linear time (O(n+m+k) instead of O(n * (m+k) - where n length of input 1, m,k - length of 2 other strings)

Comment: im not sure how to apply this to a list of `<T>`. this example only shows 1 source input.

Comment: @RPM1984 - this function (almost) converts 2 strings into dictionary of (word to word count). Call it for each element (like `foos.Select(x => ConvertToDictionary(x.a, x.b)`)

Comment: Rather than use `ToLowerInvariant()`, you would be better off to use extension method syntax of `GroupBy()` so you can pass `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` to the overload that accepts an `IEqualityComparer<>`. Something like: `matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).GroupBy(v => v, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count())`.

Comment: @RPM1984 actually there are two inputs. a and b. a simple concat joined them together...however if you need a List<string> input (how do you do a string search in T?) that is actually even easier.

Comment: @dahlbyk I had considered that as a possible method. However I was lazy as I would also need to put in the compare into the ToDictionary, as its not known what case you might get for the `g.Key`.

Comment: Good point, the ToDictionary() call also requires the same comparer.